# Find a particular subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

What kind of subset S of $\mathbb{R}$ that has the properties

1. $S$ is uncountable
2. $S \cap (1,3)$ is countable

Comment: Hint: if you can find a set which satisfies $1,2,4$, then you can just tack on an uncountable set 'below' $(0,1)$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why are you answering PSQs...

Comment: The title and question appear to be about different questions. The title suggests you want an example of such a set, and your question appears to be asking for some kind of characterization of (or at least some nontrivial properties of) such sets. Also, since the meaning of countable varies (sometimes means countably infinite, sometimes means finite or countably infinite), you may want say what "countable" means for you. However, this last part is not important since any example for one meaning is easily converted into (indeed, in one case it automatically is) an example of the other meaning.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro they had edited the question an hour ago to a completely different one (I'm guessing from the same homework assignment?) which in any case I don't think is allowed. I now feel bad for answering in the first place

Answer (score 0):

How about $$ S = (-1,0)\cup \{1-\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}?$$ I think that should work. Clearly $\sup S = 1$ (because $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$); $1$ is obviously not in $S$; it’s uncountable because $(-1,0)\subseteq S$; and finally $S\cap (0,1) = \{1-\frac{1}{n} : n\in \mathbb{N}\}\setminus \{0\}$ is countable because it’s a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Not sure that the final statement is true

Comment: @Ulice you doubt that a subset of $\Bbb Q$, a countable set, will be countable?

Comment: @Ulice a countable set cannot contain an uncountable subset

Answer (score 0):

you can take S to be all the negative real numbers and add the rationals between 0 and 1(exclusive),
it's obvious that S is uncountable, 1 isn't in S, and supS=1.
S's intersection with (0,1) will be all the rationals between 0 and 1, which is a countable set.